# Typescript default import from installed module not working correctly

Tags: typescript, import

I'm trying to use 'weaviate-ts-client' from my project, and there's something wrong in my typescript configuration but can't find it.

I'm importing default export from library like this

```ts
import weaviate from 'weaviate-ts-client';

weaviate.client(...) // gives me an ts error, Property 'client' does not exist on type 'typeof import
```

as it errors, ts suggests me to do this

```ts
import weaviate from 'weaviate-ts-client';

weaviate.default.client(...)
```

If I do above, ts compilation error is resolved but in runtime it does not works and bares me an error of TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'client')

In fact, weaviate is actually importing default export declared from index.d.ts

```ts
declare const app: {
    client: (params: ConnectionParams) => WeaviateClient;
    ApiKey: typeof ApiKey;
    AuthUserPasswordCredentials: typeof AuthUserPasswordCredentials;
    AuthAccessTokenCredentials: typeof AuthAccessTokenCredentials;
    AuthClientCredentials: typeof AuthClientCredentials;
    EmbeddedOptions: typeof EmbeddedOptions;
};
export default app;
```

and when I console log weaviate, the default import actually works as expected in runtime!

```ts
import weaviate from 'weaviate-ts-client';

console.log(weaviate);


// {
//   client: [Function: client],
//   ApiKey: [class Ci],
//   AuthUserPasswordCredentials: [class Kt],
//   AuthAccessTokenCredentials: [class Xe],
//   AuthClientCredentials: [class Zt],
//   EmbeddedOptions: [class ts]
// }


// But tsc still complains about this line! what??

weaviate.client(...) // Property 'client' does not exist on type 'typeof import
```

My guess was that there's something wrong with my tsconfig.json, and it looks like this

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "Node16",
    "lib": ["ES2022", "DOM"],
    "moduleResolution": "node16",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "build",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "__tests__/**/*"],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  }
}
```

Strange thing is that, this problem only occurs when I try to default import from installed packages in node_modules. All the default imports from my own modules inside src/* works just fine as expected.

I tried to change moduleResolution to `node` from `node-16`. by doing this the ts compilation error is resolved, but it gives me runtime error of `ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope` instead.

I also tried to add or remove esModuleInterop or allowSyntheticDefaultImports but nothing worked.

Technically I can just ignore out the wrong ts compilation errors, but I want to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who wonders what was wrong for this, I actually found out that nothing was wrong with my project configuration, but this problem originated from misconfiguration of the dependency module `weaviate-ts-client`.

Apparently, there are a lot of chaoses going on with module/moduleResolution Node16/NodeNext configuration as the resolution algorithm of it kinda deprecated a lot of past configurations for projects and now it requires a lot of packages to update their configuration to match its new behavior, and this kinda triggering a lot of problems in a lot of places.

You can check if the dependency you're trying to use has misconfigured typescript settings from here [arethetypeswrong](https://arethetypeswrong.github.io/?p=weaviate-ts-client%401.0.0)

Here are some references that might help you guide through this problem
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49160

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53759

https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/issues/104